# wxpython wx.Notebook does not get any width

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to create a project tool with a wx.Notebook with tabs at the top and a general panel at the bottom. The bottom panel should be independent of the notebook and not change when the tabs change. When I only add the notebook the notebook itself works fine, but when I also add my bottom panel (an extended wx.Panel) the notebook gets squeezed like shown in the image [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ayr69k&s=6).

I have one panel for the window and add the notebook and bottom panel (called BottomGroup, extending wx.Panel) to separate panels. Can anyone spot the trouble? Maybe something with the sizers? My Window is like this (nevermind that the tabbing is wrong):

```
class Window(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title)
    self.InitUI()


def InitUI(self):    

    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    menu = wx.Menu()
    menu_load = menu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, 'Open', 'Open project')
    menu_save = menu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, 'Save', 'Save project')
    menu_save_as = menu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, 'Save as', 'Save project as')
    menu_exit = menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit', 'Quit application')
    menuBar.Append(menu, '&File')
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    mainPanel = wx.Panel(self)

    self.noteBookPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel)
    self.notebook = wx.Notebook(self.noteBookPanel)
    self.bottomPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel)
    self.bottomGroup = BottomGroup(self.bottomPanel)

    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    self.pageNodePathsTables = PageNodesPathsTables(self.notebook)
    self.pageEscapeCriteria = PageEscapeCriteria(self.notebook)
    self.pageFileHandling = PageFileHandling(self.notebook)

    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageNodePathsTables, "Define Paths and Nodes")
    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageEscapeCriteria, "Define Escape Criteria")
    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageFileHandling, "File Handling")

    mainSizer.Add(self.noteBookPanel,1,wx.TOP)
    mainSizer.Add(self.bottomGroup,1,wx.BOTTOM)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSave, menu_save)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onLoad, menu_load)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, menu_exit)

    self.SetDimensions(WindowOpenX,WindowOpenY,WindowWidth,WindowHeight) 
    self.Show(True)
```

**Update:**

I have refactored my code to this (only the refactored part shown):

```
    self.notebook = wx.Notebook(self)
    self.bottomGroup = BottomGroup(self)

    self.setupMenu()

    #frameSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(rowGap,columnGap)
    #frameSizer.Add(self.notebook,pos=(0,0), span=(1,1),
    #              flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border = 5)
    #frameSizer.Add(self.bottomGroup,pos=(1,0), span=(1,1),
    #              flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND, border = 5)

    frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    frameSizer.Add(self.notebook, 2, wx.EXPAND)
    frameSizer.Add(self.bottomGroup,0)
    self.SetSizer(frameSizer)
```

where `self.setupMenu()` is defined as:

```
def setupMenu(self):
    self.pageNodePathsTables = PageNodesPathsTables(self.notebook)
    self.pageEscapeCriteria = PageEscapeCriteria(self.notebook)
    self.pageFileHandling = PageFileHandling(self.notebook)
    self.pagePlotHistoryData = PagePlotHistoryData(self.notebook)
    self.pageCalculateEscape = PageCalculateEscape(self.notebook)

    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageNodePathsTables, "Define Paths and Nodes")
    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageEscapeCriteria, "Define Escape Criteria")
    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageFileHandling, "File Handling")
    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pagePlotHistoryData, "Plot History Data")
    self.notebook.AddPage(self.pageCalculateEscape, "Calculate Escape")
```

This is a lot clearer and easier than the above code. It works fine, except that the `bottomGroup` is now stacked upon the `notebook` (i.e. both elements start at the upper left corner of the wx.Frame). I have tried both the `wx.BoxSizer` and the `wx.GridBagLayout` (as commented out above). Do you have any suggestions to this problem?

My BottomGroup is defined like this:

```
class BottomGroup(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self,parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
    panelSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(rowGap,columnGap)

    btnSaveProject = wx.Button(parent, label="Save project", size=(100,50))
    btnLoadProject = wx.Button(parent, label="Open project", size=(100,50))

    panelSizer.Add(btnSaveProject, pos=(0,0), span=(1,1),
                             flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT, border = borderWidth)
    panelSizer.Add(btnLoadProject, pos=(0,1), span=(1,1),
                             flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT, border = borderWidth)

    self.SetSizer(panelSizer)
```

My main method is like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Window(None, WindowHeader)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to provide you with a full solution, but rather a little advice on UI programming.

You screwed up by creating to many panels and never setting a sizer. *Before writing UI code* always think of the structure (hierarchy) of widgets you want to create. Think of their layout. Then write down the code, grouped by principle of locality: approximately one level of the hierarchy should be handled in a few lines.

Good, let's apply the principle. Notebook and bottom panel at top level:

```
wx.Frame  
 +- wx.NoteBook
     +- PageNodesPathsTables
     +- ...
 +- BottomGroup
```

At this level, everything comes down to these four, simple lines:

```python
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(self.notebook, 2, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.Add(self.bottomPanel, 0)
self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Obviously you know how to handle a `wx.NoteBook` properly. Very important is the call to  `self.SetSizer` (non-existent in your code), because otherwise the frame has no idea which sizer it should use for layouting its children.
You demands about the partitioning in two halves where pretty clear. Words of wisdom: Don't do more nesting than needed. This might be more extensible (and can easily be postponed), but at the moment it's not needed. If you do something like this:

```python
self.bottomPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel)
self.bottomGroup = BottomGroup(self.bottomPanel)
```

You have introduced at least one level (`self.bottomPanel`) with a single child (`self.bottomGroup`)  that has no clue how to layout its child components. Erase the unnecessary nesting, and you will get rid of panel creation, sizer creation, sizer assignment, and so on. Collapsing it will get you a quicker overview. Todo:

- Rewrite this section of you program. Get rid of superfluous instructions.
- Make sure every panel has a sizer.
- Refactor menu creation in a separate method.
- Parameter `parent` in the Window constructor is unused. Fix.
- Your example was missing a main method, imports, etc. Next time, supply an [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and constructive post. I have refactored my code as you suggested and updated my original post. It works fine, except that the two widgets added to the wx.Frame are now stacked upon eachother. Can you tell why?

Comment: Jeez, I was adding the buttons to the parent, not to the panel itself. Thank you, I have a much better understanding of UI layouts now.